# How to find the most frequent words in a vector using r

Tags: r

This is how my code would look like:

```
set <- c("Title", "Another one", "They can have a lot of characters") #and so on
name.set <- c("First","Second","Third")
names(set) <- name.set
```

*This is just an example, the real data set has about 800 rows and 10 variables. What is important to notice is that the values in "set" can have multiple words.*

I would like to have a code that examines each of the words (word by word) in the data set and returns to me the most frequent ones.

Comment: Try with `table` i.e. `tbl <- table(unlist(strsplit(set, "\\s+")));sort(tbl, decreasing = TRUE)[1]`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, it worked!